# How to post data using Retrofit as raw JSON

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to post data using retrofit2 in the from of raw JSON to the server but there is no response from the server. Progress bar keeps on loading but there is  no response from the server.

My server is sending below JSON object as a success message:

```
{
"status": "Success",
"statusCode": "S001",
"loginResponse": {
    "authenticationStatus": false,
    "sessionid": null,
    "errorDescription": null,
    "predictionStatus": null,
    "predictionPercentage": null,
    "predictionPercentageA": null,
    "predictionPercentageB": null,
    "predictionPercentageC": null
 }
}
```

I want to check for only `status` whether it's `Success` or not so I made below POJO class `LoginResponse` for that.

**LoginResponse**

```
public class LoginResponse {

@SerializedName("status")
String status;

public LoginResponse(){

}

public LoginResponse(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
}
```

Below is my code:

**ApiService.class**

```
public interface ApiService {

@POST("userLoginVerification")
Call<LoginResponse> getResponse(@Body JsonObject body);
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    login = findViewById(R.id.login);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    pwd = findViewById(R.id.pwd);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final ProgressDialog prg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prg.setCancelable(false);
            prg.setMessage("Logging in...");
            prg.show();

            String str1 = email.getText().toString();
            String str2 = pwd.getText().toString();

            if(str1.equals("")){

                prg.dismiss();
                TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter email",TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        TastyToast.ERROR).show();
            }
            else if(str2.equals("")){

                prg.dismiss();
                TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter password",TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        TastyToast.ERROR).show();
            }
            else{

                Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
                ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

                JsonObject jsonObject= new JsonObject();
                jsonObject.addProperty("userId",str1);
                jsonObject.addProperty("password",str2);

                Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.getResponse(jsonObject);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

                       try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(resp);

                            String str = jsonObject1.getString("status");

                            if(str.equals("Success")){

                                prg.dismiss();
                                email.setText("");
                                pwd.setText("");
                            }
                           }
                          catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                        TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                   TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
  }
```

There is no response from the server on implementing above code. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response)`

Don't create `JSONObject` in `onResponse`. `response.body()` gives you LoginResponse object. Use that object to get status. Dismiss your progress bar immediately after `onResponse` or `onFailure` if activity or fragment is not destroyed.

Comment: That means I should remove  `try-catch` block  and simply use `resp` string.

Comment: Yes. Use `response`

Answer (score 1):

In your ApiService

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("userLoginVerification")
Call<User> getResponse(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> data);
```

And the HashMap

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("userId", "theUserId");
        map.put("password", "thePassword");
```

Also, a big problem is that your response is in format

```
{ "status": "Success" }
```

but in `ApiService` you expect server return a user!
You must change the `getResponse` return type to match the server response format.

Another problem is in the line

```
if (response.equals("Success"))
```

this condition is never true, because `response` is not `String` and you cant check equality in this way. you should use `response.body()`.

Comment: Hey I have added my complete server response above and changed my ApiService returntype accordingly please go through my code and let me know   what is wrong as its still not autheticating user.

Comment: I think your data do not sent correctly. you should use `@FieldMap` in your `getResponse` method (like my answer) . if you want to use `@Body` you should create a POJO class for `getResponse` argument